# Mysql Master to Master Configuration Steps

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

In our project currently we are using Mysql Master to Master replication, both mysql server version is mysql 5.1. we are going to upgrade the replication then our requirement is one mysql server should be mysql 5.1 and another one should be mysql 5.5. that is what we have to do. if we do that, what are the problems we can face? what are all the thing should be avoid while we will be doing that? please give us some suggestion if already you had done that.

Comment: Have you read the official docs? [Upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

Comment: Watch out for the new performance schema and the mysql.events table.  You _might_ have to exclude them from replication.

Comment: ya yoonix already we had gone through the Upgrading mysql document here we are replicating the tables which we have created not mysql standard tables and we are using statement based replication.